# ¿Cómo contar la cantidad de caracteres específicos en una string de C?

Tags: c, string, bucle-for

Tengo una actividad en la que tengo que crear una función para que cuente la cantidad de "a" y "A" que hay dentro de una string. Lo que hice fue que se lea la string con un gets en la función main y después pasarla como parámetro a la funcion del ejercicio. Una vez en la función, recorro el array de caracteres (la string) con un for. Para contar las letras a comparo caracter por caracter con otras variables usando un if y en caso de la condicion sea verdadera aumenta una variable por 1. Si se llega al caracter nulo se usa un break para salir del for. El problema es que el programa no toma ninguna letra como una A o a y sale de for dando de salida Hay 0 As en la oracion.
Código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int aa(char arr[], int num){
 int i;
 int b=0;
 int a='a';
 int a1='A';
 for(i=0;i<num;i++){/*El problema esta en este for*/
 if(arr[i]==((a)||(a1))){
 b++;}/*El programa no cuenta ningun caracter como a o A*/
 else if(arr[i]=='\0'){
 break;}}/*Y directamente sale de la funcion*/
 printf("Hay %d As en la oracion.\n",b);}


main(){
 int i;
 char string1[64];
 printf("Poner una oracion:\n");
 gets(string1);
 aa(string1,64);
 return 759;}
```

edit: Listo ya esta solucionado, gracias :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
if( arr[i] == ( ( a ) || ( a1 ) ) ) {
```

Eso equivale a

> compara el valor de `arr[i]` con el resultado de realizar un *or lógico* entre `a` y `a1`

Lo que tú quieres hacer es:

```
if( ( arr[i] == a ) || ( arr[i] == a1 ) ) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Mejorando tu código, quedaría así, después de arreglar algunos problemas de lógica y estructura.

Para comparar con caracteres puedes hacerlo así:

```
if(arr[i] == 'a' || arr[i] == 'A') //no hace falta guardar los caracteres 'a' y 'A' en variables.
```

Tu código completo quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int aa(char arr[], int num){
   int i;
   int b=0;

   for(i=0;i<num;i++){
     if(arr[i]=='a'|| arr[i]=='A'){
        b++;
     }
     else if(arr[i]=='\0')
        break;
 }
 printf("Hay %d As en la oracion.\n",b);}


main(){
   int i;
   char string1[64];
   printf("Poner una oracion:\n");
   gets(string1);
   aa(string1,64);
   return 759;
}
```

Comment: También te recomendaría utilizar nombres de variables y funciones más legibles, por ejemplo para la función aa, llamarla por ejemplo `contadorDeCaracteres()`, esto no es obligatorio pero es una buena práctica.

Answer (score 0):

El anterior código no funciona.
El que pego a continuación sí que funciona. Lo he probado. 
Cuando se pega un código lo mínimo es probarlo para no despistar a los que lo encuentren en sus búsquedas.

```
/*
 ============================================================================
 Name        : numerodea.c
 Author      : Sergio Sanz
 Version     :
 Copyright   : All Rights Reserved
 ============================================================================
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int aa(char arr[], int num)
{
   int i;
   int b = 0;

   for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
   {
     if(arr[i] == 'a' || arr[i] == 'A')
     {
        b++;
     }
     else if(arr[i] == '\0')
     return b;
   }
}

int main()
{
   char string1[64];

   printf("Poner una oración:\n");
   fflush(stdout);
   gets(string1);

   int num = aa(string1, 64);

   printf("Hay %d As en la oración.\n", num);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: al código de quien te refieres?

Comment: A la respuesta anterior, en la que pone que el código quedaría así..., y pega un código que no funciona. El que he puesto yo es una posible solución a la cuestión inicial, que sí que funciona realmente, porque está probado. Eso es lo que quería decir.